# SPDY and lazy image loading via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, request, spdy

I'd like to load a bunch of images via JavaScript and insert them into my page. When the web server supports SPDY, does each image generate a new request  or are all the image request bundled into one SPDY request? Are there some methods that do this (for example creating `img` tags in the DOM) and others that don't? Are there differences in browser behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images you want to load from JavaScript are static (i.e. not generated on the fly, or chosen on the fly by the server), then a SPDY server that supports SPDY Push can serve these images along with the primary resource (usually the HTML page that loads the JavaScript).

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) is one of the few servers that supports SPDY Push in a transparent way for applications.
You can look up the documentation about Jetty's SPDY support [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy.html), and a blog about details of the SPDY Push configuration [here](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/06/spdy-we-push/) (official documentation is coming).

[Here](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/10/spdy-push-demo-from-javaone-2012/) you can find a video that shows the difference that SPDY Push makes.

If you're not using a server that is SPDY Push enabled, then every each image will generate a new request to the server (unless they are otherwise cached by the browser from previous requests).

Chrome already supports SPDY Push, Firefox will support it soon.

Comment: Which images I want to load is decided dynamically on the client, so I can't push :(